# Programmatically Generating EF Core Migrations Fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm creating a Console app which will generate and apply EF Core migrations for referenced assemblies.

The code I've got will create the first migration correctly but it fails with the following error when trying to create any subsequent migrations:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The model must be finalized and its runtime dependencies must be initialized before 'GetRelationalModel' can be used. Ensure that either 'OnModelCreating' has completed or, if u
sing a stand-alone 'ModelBuilder', that 'IModelRuntimeInitializer.Initialize(model.FinalizeModel())' was called.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalModelExtensions.GetRelationalModel(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
```

Here is the code (I've abbreviated or removed things that aren't relevant, such as writing the files):

```
var references = new[]
{
    typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location,
    typeof(Console).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location,
    typeof(MigrationBuilder).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location,
    typeof(ModelBuilder).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location,
    typeof(Action).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location,
    typeof(Expression<>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location,
    typeof(System.Runtime.AssemblyTargetedPatchBandAttribute).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location,
    typeof(BinaryExpression).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location,
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Single(a => a.GetName().Name == "netstandard").Location,
    Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(System.Runtime.GCSettings).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
                "System.Runtime.dll"),
}.Select(r => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(r)).ToArray();
        
var ctxType = dbContext.GetType();
var ctxAssemblyRefPath = ctxType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location;
var ctxAssemblyMetaData = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(ctxAssemblyRefPath);

// The migrationsDirectory contains the migration classes along with the model snapshot class
var migrationsDirectory = GetMigrationsDirectory();
var assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        
var syntaxTrees = Directory
    .GetFiles(migrationsDirectory)
    .Select(File.ReadAllText)
    .Select(f => CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(f));

var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
    assemblyName,
    syntaxTrees,
    references: references.Concat(new[] { ctxAssemblyMetaData }),
    options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

using var ms = new MemoryStream();

compilation.Emit(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            
var assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(ms);
var prop = ctxType.BaseType?.GetProperty("MigrationAssembly");
prop.SetValue(null, assembly.GetName().FullName);
            
var ctxInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(ctxType) as GwrsDbContext;
            
designTimeServices = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton<IOperationReporter>(new OperationReporter(null))
                .AddSingleton<MigrationsCodeGeneratorDependencies>()
                .AddSingleton<ValueConverterSelectorDependencies>()
                .AddSingleton<IValueConverterSelector, ValueConverterSelector>()
                .AddSingleton<TypeMappingSourceDependencies>()
                .AddSingleton<RelationalTypeMappingSourceDependencies>()
                .AddSingleton<ITypeMappingSource, RelTypeMappingSource>()
                .AddSingleton<ICSharpHelper, CSharpHelper>()
                .AddSingleton<AnnotationCodeGeneratorDependencies>()
                .AddSingleton<IAnnotationCodeGenerator, AnnotationCodeGenerator>()
                .AddSingleton<CSharpMigrationOperationGeneratorDependencies>()
                .AddSingleton<ICSharpMigrationOperationGenerator, CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator>()
                .AddSingleton<CSharpSnapshotGeneratorDependencies>()
                .AddSingleton<ICSharpSnapshotGenerator, CSharpSnapshotGenerator>()
                .AddSingleton<CSharpMigrationsGeneratorDependencies>()
                .AddSingleton<IMigrationsCodeGenerator, CSharpMigrationsGenerator>()
                .AddSingleton<MigrationsScaffolderDependencies>()
                .AddSingleton<MigrationsScaffolder>()
                .AddSingleton<IRegisteredServices, RegisteredServices>()
                .AddSingleton<IPropertyParameterBindingFactory, PropertyParameterBindingFactory>()
                .AddSingleton<IParameterBindingFactories, ParameterBindingFactories>()
                .AddSingleton<IConstructorBindingFactory, ConstructorBindingFactory>()
                .AddSingleton<RuntimeModelDependencies>()
                .AddSingleton<IMemberClassifier, MemberClassifier>()
                .AddSingleton<ModelValidatorDependencies>()
                .AddSingleton<IModelValidator, ModelValidator>()
                .AddSingleton<ModelRuntimeInitializerDependencies>()
                .AddSingleton<IModelRuntimeInitializer, ModelRuntimeInitializer>()
                .AddSingleton<ISnapshotModelProcessor, SnapshotModelProcessor>()
                .AddSingleton<MigrationBuilder>()
                .AddSingleton<IMigrationsCodeGeneratorSelector, MigrationsCodeGeneratorSelector>();
                .AddSingleton(ctxInstance.GetService<IHistoryRepository>())
                .AddSingleton(ctxInstance.GetService<IMigrationsIdGenerator>())
                .AddSingleton(ctxInstance.GetService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>())
                .AddSingleton(ctxInstance.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>())
                .AddSingleton(ctxInstance.GetService<IDesignTimeModel>().Model)
                .AddSingleton(ctxInstance.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>())
                .AddSingleton(ctxInstance.GetService<IDatabaseProvider>())
                .AddSingleton(ctxInstance.GetService<IRelationalTypeMappingSource>())
                .AddSingleton(ctxInstance.GetService<IMigrator>());
            
var serviceProvider = designTimeServices.BuildServiceProvider();
            
string migrationName = GenerateMigrationName();

var scaffolder = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MigrationsScaffolder>();
var migration = scaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(migrationName, GetRootNamespace());

// Files are written out here
```

I'm testing it with a really simple DbContext implementation:

```
public class DevelopmentContext : DbContext
{
    public static string? MigrationAssembly { get; set; }
    
    public DevelopmentContext()
    {
        var folder = Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData;
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
        DbPath = Path.Join(path, "development1.db");
    }
    
    public string DbPath { get; }
    
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; }

    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; }
    
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}", a =>
        {
            if (MigrationAssembly != null)
            {
                a.MigrationsAssembly(MigrationAssembly);
            }
        });
    }
}
```